# how to prevent "note : Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead"

Tags: mysql, innodb

my problem is that i run `mysqlcheck` for InnoDB tables in a Cronjob and if i get everytime an e-mail with thousands of these messages i will easily overlook possible error messages.

`--silent` does not help either.

my best try till now is to 
`| grep -v "note     :"` 
but i fear that i could be stripping out more important "notes"...

But even so `mysqlcheck` is listing every table in the DB which is already a pretty long list, still hiding possible error messages.

i haven't been able to find any relevant information about exit codes of `mysqlcheck`, for instance, to just send an e-mail if there is really something wrong.

so the question is:
"How to run `mysqlcheck` and just get **RELEVANT** output"?

Comment: what is/are your table type(s)?

Comment: Hi e4c5, innodb as stated in the question... it is not about understanding the messages, i know what they mean and what the alternatives are.

Comment: Let's answer a question "why do you need to run it".

Comment: Hi akuzminsky, that is a good question, but isn't it a good practice to do periodic maintenance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is:  Don't use mysqlcheck on InnoDB.  And use only InnoDB.

The error message comes from `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, which is all but useless for InnoDB.  (It had *some* use for MyISAM.)  InnoDB is good at keeping its tables in decent shape.  That is, 99.9% of the time `OPTIMIZE` is a waste of time.

**Addenda**

Sure, InnoDB gets fragmented.  Any BTree gets fragmented.  (This includes MyISAM indexes, which are BTree-organized.)  BTrees, even under heavy modification, tend to go from 0% fragmented to an *average* of 31% "free" space, then stay there.  Sure, you *could* defragment to get that back, but further activity would promptly lose it.  It's not worth the effort and downtime.

That 31% does not translate into anything more than a negligible slowdown.  Yes, it is a chunk of disk space, but optimize needs 100% to do its task because it copies the table over.  So, you clearly have enough disk space.

Comment: are you telling me that innodb is maintenance free?
do i really don't have to do ANYTHING? NEVER?
no fragmentation risk? really?

Comment: Crashes:  MyISAM needs `REPAIR TABLE` after most crashes, InnoDB does not.  InnoDB can get hosed, but that is much less common.

Comment: Added more on OPTIMIZE; see addenda.  I can't think of anything else that comes under the category of "maintenance".